# Noise from the graphic card filtered in the hdmi output

Tags: audio, graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-geforce

I got a brand new PC mounted with a Nvidia GTX 780 ti. It is conected to the screen with an HDMI wire, and there is also a pair of speakers conected to the screen, so I get the sound from the graphic card. 
The problem is that sometimes, when the graphic card is working,  the speakers reproduce the little electric sounds from the inside of the card. There are not realy disturbing sounds, but I wonder, is it normal? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There might be a few reasons why... Check with another HDMI cable first and then, make sure sur PC is static free and also, have the latest driver installed. To make sure, if you have another TV with HDMI input (By any chance), give it a shot.

Comment: Oh, the drivers... I instaled but forgot to restart the computer. Now the problem is solved. Thanks you for the help!

Comment: Always a good idea with Windows ;)